# How to test inner class in trigger?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have the following legacy code that I have to test:

```
trigger reportingTargetsChanged on Reporting_Targets__c (after insert, after update)
    List<Reporting_Targets__c> reportingDatas = [SELECT ...]
    ProjectPerformanceUpdater projectPerformanceUpdater = new ProjectPerformanceUpdater();
    projectPerformanceUpdater.updatePerformances(reportingDatas);

    private class ProjectPerformanceUpdater {
        public void updatePerformances(List<Reporting_Targets__c> targetDatas) {
            List<String> projectPerformancesKeys =new List<String>();
            for(Reporting_Targets__c targetsData : targetsDatas) {
                projectPerformancesKeys.add(targetsData.Resource_Request__r.Project_Performance__r.Id);
            }
            List<Project_Performance__c> performances = [SELECT Id FROM Project_Performance__c WHERE Id IN :projectPerformancesKeys];

            List<Project_Performance__c> updatedPerformances = new List<Project_Performance__c>();
            for(Project_Performance__c performance : performances) {
                boolean isUpdated = updatePerformance(performance);
                if(isUpdated) {
                    updatedPerformances.add(performance);
                }
            }
            if(updatedPerformances.size() > 0) {
                update updatedPerformances;
            }

        private boolean updatePerformance(Project_Performance__c performance) {
            //CODE NOT UNDER CODE COVERAGE
        }
 }
```

I tried everything to insert any appropriate data in the Project_Performance__c table, but because of the data structure that's not possible. So I hoped that there is another way to test this method.

I know how to test an inner class per se, so I added the @TestVisible Annotation to the class and the method, but I don't know how to instantiate the class to test it. I would really appreciate help with this, as I cannot get the code coverage high enough without testing this part.

Comment: If you write a test related to your trigger, the inner class will be called. The problem comes from the fact that your test is badly written. The data inserted in your test doesn't cover the case. also, you shouldn't have inner classes in triggers. You should create a new class outside the trigger.

Comment: `I tried everything to insert any appropriate data in the Project_Performance__c table, but because of the data structure that's not possible.` -- you need to elaborate on this.

Comment: @copredy The problem is that the Project_Performance__c table is empty to begin with. I tried to insert data in the test, before triggering the trigger, but there is a master detail that I cannot write, not even for the first time I generate the data. I get the error message, that the field is not writeable, not writing it results in a required field missing error. Every solution I found on the internet was not working for me. Without data in that table this path obviously wont be executed during the test. I might do something wrong, just started with apex not long ago.

Comment: @MartinLezer what would be the appropriate way to refactor this code? I thought about creating a new class, but was not sure if there is something like a rule in apex about inner classes in triggers or something. Would you just create a new public class? That way it could be used from others, but I'm currently the only one working on this project and it'll probably be completely reworked next year.